# How to i draw graph in iphone application?

Tags: iphone

Hey i take core plot but i cant properly set up such y i cant get `#import <CorePlot/coreplot.h>` header file. i read somewhere we have to use full view for one graph but we can add graph in part of view as sub view...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for simple line graph you can also use s7graphview. just need to include two files.

Comment: hey nanda i got ur point i shot look at s7graphview but i didnt get its syntax like tableView where we have to send y axis values how to we send that value via array or else other method                                                           And if u have some demo on s7GraphView than pls send it to me Thank you in advance

Comment: hey javal if u have time than give me answer of my this que NO. 4438343 on stackoverflow i  use touch XML for parsing data

Answer (score 1):

CorePlot is an external library; it is not part of the iOS SKD. Start by downloading it and including it on your XCode project:

http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/

Comment: hey Felz i try work on core plot but i can`t add , i follow step give in read me file but i got error in UIKit default library

Comment: i try to add this framework but too many error i got, than i solve all  them than i have obj_class_Ref. type some error occur please tell me manage this type of error in my settings.......

Answer (score 1):

check out two methods for passing array for x values and y values:

```
   - (NSArray *)graphViewXValues:(S7GraphView *)graphView {
/* An array of objects that will be further formatted to be displayed on the X-axis.
 The number of elements should be equal to the number of points you have for every plot. */
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:101];
for ( int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++ ) {
    [array addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:i]];   
}
return array;
```

}

```
- (NSArray *)graphView:(S7GraphView *)graphView yValuesForPlot:(NSUInteger)plotIndex {
/* Return the values for a specific graph. Each plot is meant to have equal number of points.
 And this amount should be equal to the amount of elements you return from graphViewXValues: method. */
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:2.355450986],[NSNumber numberWithInt:2.799548641],[NSNumber numberWithInt:3.614688072],
                        [NSNumber numberWithInt:4.34234145],[NSNumber numberWithInt:4.992897896],[NSNumber numberWithInt:5.575169066],
                        [NSNumber numberWithInt:6.096775274],[NSNumber numberWithInt:6.564430346],[NSNumber numberWithInt:6.984123338],
                        [NSNumber numberWithInt:7.361236116],[NSNumber numberWithInt:7.700624405],[NSNumber numberWithInt:8.006677447],
                        [NSNumber numberWithInt:8.283364855],[NSNumber numberWithInt:8.534275028],[NSNumber numberWithInt:8.762648582],
                        [NSNumber numberWithInt:8.971407287],[NSNumber numberWithInt:9.163180317],[NSNumber numberWithInt:9.340328068],
                        [NSNumber numberWithInt:9.504964014],[NSNumber numberWithInt:9.658974787],[NSNumber numberWithInt:9.804039109],
                        [NSNumber numberWithInt:9.941644878],[NSNumber numberWithInt:10.07310549],[NSNumber numberWithInt:10.19957488],
                        [NSNumber numberWithInt:10.32206165],[NSNumber numberWithInt:10.4414422],[NSNumber numberWithInt:10.55847309],
                        [NSNumber numberWithInt:10.67380261],[NSNumber numberWithInt:10.78798156],[NSNumber numberWithInt:10.90147346],
                        [NSNumber numberWithInt:11.01466395],[NSNumber numberWithInt:11.12786972],[NSNumber numberWithInt:11.24134752],
                        [NSNumber numberWithInt:11.3552982],[NSNumber numberWithInt:11.46987977],[NSNumber numberWithInt:11.58520959],
                        [NSNumber numberWithInt:11.70137143],[NSNumber numberWithInt:11.75978387],nil];
```

return array;
}

Comment: hey javal i made proper code for it i get graphView BUT it comes blank because This four delegate method didnt call.... i can`t set its delegate too....Please give me way from it... and...i set some property to that graph but thye also not shown..... forget it but first of all give some way for how to call that deleg. method

Comment: i got answer, m not set datasource to self thank you javal for my give me ur some time.... if i have sm prob on this i add comment buddy

Comment: @Javal Nanda: Instead of posting the code as seperate answer you can Edit your first answer and put all the code there. So there are no multiple answers by the same user.